# ¿Cómo puedo definir una variable Google_Service_Drive correctamente con Google Drive API usando PHP para crear una carpeta?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Soy nuevo en esto así que espero puedan ayudarme, estoy revisando la documentación de [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) porque deseo crear una carpeta in Google Drive usando PHP, estoy usando el código de ejemplo pero noto que debo definir esta variable "$driveService" primero.

Debo decir que antes hice los pasos previos (Crear un proyecto, instalar via composer, generar mi archivo client_secret.json, etc).

Por tanto he intentado usar el ejemplo con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
 require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('64*****-client_secret.json');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php');
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

 $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
   'name' => 'TEST',
   'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));

 $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));

 printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);

?>
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto la página no se muestra nada en el navegador, esto en lo que muestra en el terminal:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with 
 message '{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
  {
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "required",
  "message": "Login Required",
  "locationType": "header",
  "location": "Authorization"
  }
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Login Required"
}
}
' in /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() in /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

He adicionado estas líneas:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('64*****-client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php');
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
```

Pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, no puedo crear la carpeta ni el ID de la misma, cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Agradeceré su respuesta.

Comment: ya has generado el accessToken en algún momento? lo estás guardando? ya que si lo haces mediante `setAccessType('offline')` tienes que pasar el accesToken mediante `$client->setAccessToken({tu_token});`

Comment: @Sr1871 Anteriormente hice el quickstart developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php  el cuál me generó un archivo token.json, incluso he reemplazado la variable client con la función getClient() e igual tengo el problema

Comment: y ese token que te generó lo guardaste en algún lado? como dije anteriormente ese token debes pasarlo a través de `setAccesToken(...)`;

Comment: @Sr1871 Sí, ese archivo está guardado en la misma carpeta dónde está el archivo php, cuando lo ejecuto ahora me muestra en terminal lo siguiente: `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" }}'`

Comment: porbablemente generaste el token antes de generar el scopte, entra a https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions y revisa si tu cuenta tiene esos permisos dados a dive

Comment: @Sr1871 Sí tengo accesos a Drive

Comment: @Sr1871 En todo caso, si no quiero hacerlo offline, cómo puedo solucionar el problema inicial?

Comment: Si no lo pones offline vas a tener que estar dando acceso manual con clics cada vez que quieras realizar una operación, ahorita te pongo una solución offline para ver si te funciona

Answer (score 0):

Ingresa a https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions y elimina los permisos que tienes del drive

Después ingresa a https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={tuClientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code&access_type=offline

suponiendo que tu redirectUrl es https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php

Entonces en tu `oauth2callback.php` tendrás que hacer una llamada post

Este ejemplo es usando el `$client` del `GuzzleHttp` pero tu puedes hacerlo de la forma que quieras

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($this->clientId);
    $client->setClientSecret($this->clientSecret);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $clientGuzzle = new Client(); //cliente Guzzle


    $response = $clientGuzzle->request('POST', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', [
      'form_params' => [
          'code' =>$_GET['code'],
          'client_id' => $clientId,
          'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
          'redirect_uri' => $redirectUrl,
          'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
      ]
  ]);
     $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
     if(strpos($content, 'refresh_token') === false) {
         throw new  \Exception("La respuesta no contiene el refresh_token, 
          ingresa a https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions para eliminarlos y vuelve a entrar");
  }
     $client->setAccessToken($content);
     file_put_contents('accessToken.txt', json_encode($client->getAccessToken()) );
     echo "token generado";
  } else {
        echo "falta el code";
  }
```

una vez hecho esto, vuelve a tu archivo donde tienes tu código de crear la carpeta drive y cambia lo siguiente

```
 <?php
 require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
  $client = new \Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId($clientId);
  $client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  if(file_get_content('accessToken.txt')){
    $client->setAccessToken(file_get_content('accessToken.txt'));
    if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
      $client->refreshToken($newToken['refresh_token']);
      file_put_contents('accessToken.txt', json_encode($client->getAccessToken()) );
    }
  }

 $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
   'name' => 'TEST',
   'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));

 $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));

 printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);

?>
```

Obviamente puede que las rutas tanto en `file_put_contents` como en `file_get_contents` varíe de acuerdo a donde tienes los php, pero puedes calcular las rutas.

Actualmente he creado una extensión para usar youtube api guardando el accessToken para el framework, aunque tu usas google drive, la generación del accesstoken es la misma puesto que google lo generaliza

Puedes checarla para que te puedas dar una idea de como se hace el logueo por si no te quedo claro

https://github.com/sr1871/yii2-youtube-api

Comment: He tratado de ejecutar el link pero me dice que la app no está verificada en Google, ya previamente he cambiado el código del oauth2callback.php pero no funciona. Lo que hice fue borrar el archivo token y ejecuté el archivo con el código para crear la carpeta pero en el terminal: `php newfolder.php`, me dio un link que tenía que ejecutar en el browser para que me de un código y lo pegue en el terminal, sólo así se volvió a generar el archivo token y creó la carpeta, a partir de ese momento puedo crear carpetas pero siempre en el terminal, cómo hago para ejecutarlo desde el browser?

Comment: en browser en que parte te marca error? no entendí muy bien

Comment: Simplemente ejecuto el archivo `newfolder.php` (archivo que crea la carpeta) en el browser y sólo muestra la pantalla en blanco, cuando me debería mostrar el ID de la carpeta creada, pero si voy al terminal y ejecuto vía comandos `php newfolder.php` sí funciona, me muestra el ID de la carpeta en el terminal y se muestra la carpeta creada en Google Drive. ¿Cómo hago para que esto funcione también al ejecutarlo en el browser? Porque pareciera  que los ejemplos de Google funcionan sólo vía comandos

Comment: Tienes activados los errores en php? quizá te esté marcando error y no se vea por que no tienes activados los errores en el php, si los tienes activados trata poniendo varios echos alrededor del archivo para ver hasta donde lelga

Comment: Checando los logs del servidor web:  `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This application must be run on the command line.' in /var/www/drive/newfolder.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/drive/newfolder.php on line 5 `

Comment: El token que estas utilizando para tratar de acceder al drive via web, es el que generas mediante la linea de comandos? Si es asi, puede que ese sea el problema, o al menos a mi me causo este tipo de problemas. Consulta esta pagina: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#example para ver como se obtiene el token para web. Y tambien seria de ayuda que compartas lo que tienes en tu archivo oauth2callback.php.